# python index error pop up when I have a longer input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving one sorting problem. I encountered with one problem which has been troubling me for 2 days.

I ran the code for a shorter input, it worked just as what I expected.
However, when I put a much longer input into this program, runtime error emerges.

Here is the code:

```
row_number, row_length = input().split()
row_number, row_length = int(row_number), int(row_length)
def row_input():
    data_input = []    
    for i in range(0,row_number):
        row = list(map(int,input().split()))
        data_input.append(row)
    return data_input   

def sort_data(data):
    k = int(input())
    sorted_data = []
    for row in data:
        sorted_data.append(row[k])
    sorted_data.sort()
    n = 0
    while n < row_number:
        for m in data:
            if sorted_data[n] == m[k]:
                print_data(m)
                n = n + 1

def print_data(data):
    b=''
    for n in data:
        b= b + str(n).ljust(len(str(n))+1)
    print(b)  

data = row_input()
sort_data(data)
```

Here is the short input:

```
10 3
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
2 2 5
2 3 6
2 3 7
2 3 8
2 3 9
2 4 0
1
```

Here is the longer input:

```
100 10
64 79 18 94 46 81 74 97 71 92
46 24 23 20 68 15 53 93 24 91
17 66 34 64 28 5 55 25 44 96
16 71 80 84 5 79 63 77 69 77
33 77 24 13 58 81 41 36 73 62
93 26 16 55 61 51 39 69 29 45
44 85 1 48 23 59 52 82 50 37
77 74 9 21 35 54 81 57 32 76
82 21 72 49 98 21 77 64 6 63
68 17 93 83 12 43 84 28 96 86
9 16 3 89 38 11 70 25 41 38
49 99 31 19 85 97 80 63 16 69
50 85 80 75 36 48 56 69 63 94
78 80 83 86 92 60 56 90 22 73
69 81 45 9 67 25 82 46 68 82
98 38 23 31 38 83 37 76 69 82
95 48 21 64 25 6 38 96 69 23
44 97 46 54 21 56 65 51 66 34
87 22 27 24 55 48 90 10 8 51
21 6 74 78 8 88 26 63 72 43
64 4 42 20 54 91 2 51 79 40
93 76 52 58 40 78 98 27 53 48
85 23 86 30 91 49 81 4 59 9
88 96 77 95 36 71 7 52 14 20
69 98 21 94 14 35 28 97 3 9
60 47 56 34 35 61 9 44 80 92
4 76 57 28 60 3 46 4 6 17
59 44 88 7 71 60 84 12 91 38
76 57 5 2 25 12 46 62 32 68
14 15 11 1 34 20 54 58 45 38
89 49 16 43 74 51 80 22 88 31
8 98 51 73 32 13 59 12 56 92
36 82 9 63 77 79 77 25 52 91
63 82 58 75 13 20 79 89 55 89
58 37 93 1 29 72 78 95 47 35
90 82 58 60 55 86 82 22 44 94
55 17 51 99 29 92 1 79 96 34
32 78 41 1 24 52 11 80 3 25
30 32 32 71 85 80 63 23 80 97
35 22 11 71 10 48 43 58 31 33
30 98 60 58 28 71 95 28 21 29
74 4 13 99 90 64 28 27 73 4
52 21 52 31 35 82 35 64 21 71
92 85 13 48 5 32 92 70 15 85
47 55 25 80 24 22 19 78 17 43
3 91 71 53 49 39 96 88 59 61
79 26 98 2 95 95 70 38 82 85
69 67 41 11 95 39 20 19 96 36
11 74 48 23 84 49 47 43 27 90
4 28 35 14 70 62 52 94 46 91
72 11 14 82 59 51 93 98 55 79
90 84 84 24 21 81 11 57 27 78
98 97 59 51 89 40 96 35 25 59
73 85 64 17 46 9 79 54 27 15
48 91 7 56 41 6 4 26 96 39
43 22 34 89 52 59 55 52 38 42
10 31 9 8 21 46 29 4 97 4
44 49 78 31 53 29 11 35 46 14
44 39 57 35 9 63 85 5 97 24
9 72 49 50 41 47 23 71 15 45
51 6 98 64 75 35 39 48 2 50
92 22 72 60 96 15 17 4 79 27
90 30 98 28 92 8 83 71 24 62
5 54 86 14 71 96 87 2 58 78
37 61 60 30 46 96 49 58 27 48
14 59 22 35 75 60 55 28 91 85
21 1 85 85 78 67 24 69 22 17
76 61 84 64 33 76 61 10 33 95
71 9 1 32 31 80 69 7 25 59
69 64 78 85 21 88 56 70 92 74
79 12 8 9 54 56 37 44 1 84
6 66 54 5 82 17 41 25 3 71
8 44 63 17 75 43 87 15 85 3
15 42 15 59 38 22 46 27 19 13
54 71 76 93 67 39 46 12 78 46
23 82 71 34 31 61 94 58 10 62
30 8 43 38 7 23 77 38 93 32
32 72 46 59 64 45 14 73 62 72
76 26 47 89 25 73 79 28 60 48
41 58 85 55 29 64 39 84 20 87
24 8 70 16 69 32 17 26 58 16
40 53 40 63 22 37 11 74 7 8
23 4 56 39 27 94 91 72 14 61
41 86 3 29 41 15 99 50 82 84
33 5 22 93 73 86 99 87 26 66
73 25 55 46 69 38 99 14 43 55
43 21 82 30 90 66 6 67 49 25
81 38 65 40 80 7 90 82 33 13
18 45 1 90 53 51 51 96 32 90
32 69 51 22 71 85 80 61 99 23
88 8 41 92 4 25 64 89 30 75
93 85 99 87 67 3 54 16 98 57
33 54 31 83 64 93 3 24 65 81
74 19 15 66 17 14 34 50 57 16
10 30 20 97 32 85 83 89 68 18
46 82 9 14 54 50 55 28 26 96
29 96 3 33 12 52 11 26 19 22
50 81 95 59 76 53 10 9 72 87
25 85 54 43 53 13 52 70 38 76
20 14 30 80 23 43 27 67 42 11
5
```

Here is the error while running the longer input:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 30, in <module>
    sort_data(data)
  File "solution.py", line 19, in sort_data
    if sorted_data[n] == m[k]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Perhaps I made a copy-paste mistake, but I can't reproduce your problem: I get a `IndexError: list index out of range` in line 19, not a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Please change your title as well; when I ran your code, the edited traceback was not there, and I was looking for a RuntimeError, not an IndexError. A good title is quite essential.

Comment: There is no problem for running the shorter input.

Comment: @Evert I put my code on Hackerrank, the compiler gives me a runtime error. I don't know if I need to use runtime error or index error.

Comment: IndexError: that's what's Python tells you. I don't know about Hackerrank, but if that returns a runtime error, it's doing something wrong.

Comment: @Evert Thanks. I will change the title into Indexerror. Do you have any idea how does this happen? no error for short input but for the longer one I give.

Comment: I haven't followed the complete logic of your code, but note that you essentially have the following (minus an if-clause): `while n < row_number; for m in data: n = n + 1`. The comparison in the while-clause can't prevent `n` from reaching `row_number` and above, since there is an inner loop which may increase `n` by quite a bit more than just 1 (depending on how often the if-statement is True). I would have a look at that logic and see whether it's sound.

Comment: And I bet that if you tweak the input for the short data file just right, it will also raise an IndexError.

Comment: Try the following as input, and see what you get: `2 2\n25 85\n20 14\n1\n` (I think this should be valid input, if I understand the input format correctly). For me, it raises an IndexError in the same spot. But with this little amount of input data, it should be easier to debug what's going on using a bunch of print statements.

Comment: @Evert the input logic is the first number in first row in input gives the number of rows needed to be sorted whereas the second number gives the length of the row. The last row gives the position for each row to be sorted according to the number in the position.

Comment: Your small example is already sorted. That's not a good test case! (If it's the only one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your sorting logics, because it is highly possible you increment `n` by more than one in one iteration of the while loop if there are multiple matching rows in the dataset.

The right solution is simpler than you think:

```
def sort_data(data):
    k = int(input())
    output = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row[k])
    for r in output:
        print_data(r)
```

UPDATE: The smallest dataset on what your algorithm fails is:

```
2 1
2
1
0
```

A small modification on your function will stop it from overindexing. The key is to store `sorted_data[n]` in a variable, and that way it will not try to over index `sorted_data` when no more output is expected.

```
def sort_data(data):
    k = int(input())
    sorted_data = []
    for row in data:
        sorted_data.append(row[k])
    sorted_data.sort()
    n = 0
    while n < row_number:
        key = sorted_data[n]
        for m in data:
            if key == m[k]:
                print_data(m)
                n = n + 1
```

UPDATE:

The [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function's key parameter is a function, which just selects a value what to sort by. In your case, selects the `k`th column, which is what you want to sort by.

Comment: Did you introduced a dictionary by using lambda in your answer? I'm new to python.

Comment: No, the `sorted` function will not build a dictionary, it will call the key function on the fly on every comparison it makes, however it is not documented functionality. See my updated answer for the docs

Comment: Further investigation showed that the key function is called only once for every element, so the underlying implementation might use a dictionary or more probably uses a shadow list with the mapped values.